# Save integer without quotations into firebase database in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to put a number into firebase database with setValue, but it always changes to a string when I put it in. Example: "10" instead of 10. I have double checked that the value which I am setting is actually an int or NSNumber. None of which works.

```
var modeResId = (self.modes[self.currModeNum].modeId as NSNumber)  
ref.child(Mode.Parameter.MODE_ID).setValue(modeResId)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was looking at the wrong key value. Now it works.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In that case I vote to close the question as a typo, since it's unlikely to be of help to others in the future. Also a reminder that you can often spot this type of problems by trying to recreate the behavior in isolation, as shown in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
var modeResId = (self.modes[self.currModeNum].modeId as NSNumber)  
ref.child(Mode.Parameter.MODE_ID).setValue(Int(modeResId) ?? 0) //If parsing fails then setValue 0
```

Convert `modeId` into an `Int` first and then `setValue` into firebase.

Comment: Int(modeResId) is deprecated it should use modeResId.intValue

Comment: No, I am not sending String. modeId is of type Int already. I have tried your code anyway, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Salman500 I get an error: `Value of type 'Int' has no member 'intValue'`

Comment: Yes the error is right `Int` has no `intValue`, `NSNumber has intValue`

Comment: @Salman500 No matter what I put in setValue, Int or NSNumber, I always get quotation marks around the Int

Comment: @mbostic are you saving value directly in child ?